# Is there a standard for C++ stream operators

Tags: c++

Does the C++ standard specify how a stream in/out operators should behave? Specifically which characters to be taken as separators?

Comment: Do you mean the ones that already exist, or those you define yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The reference page on [`std::istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) contains the numerical and stream overloads and how they work, and the [non-member overload for `std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) defines the other variant.

Basically, `std::isspace` is used to end the input operation.

Any `operator>>` you define yourself behaves in the exact way that you define it of course...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the [standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) specifies how I/O overloaded operators should behave in

- 27.7.2.2 Formatted input functions [istream.formatted]
- 27.7.3.6 Formatted output functions [ostream.formatted]